# How to know if code will cause a memory leak?

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization, event-handling

I am trying to determine when JS or jQuery code will cause a memory leak. Do either of the following examples cause memory leaks?

On click of btn-submit-form, call an anonymous function, that executes a bootbox confirmation which then will call another function based on the confirmation that is returned:

```
$('#btn-submit-form').click(function () { 
            bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function (confirmed) { 
                if (confirmed) { onSubmitForm(); } 
            }); 
});
```

On click of btn-submit-form, call the bootboxConfirmation function. All logic for handling the confirmation is contained within that function rather than within an anonymous function as in the first example.

```
var bootboxConfirmation = function() { 
        bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function (confirmed) { 
            if (confirmed) { onSubmitForm(); } 
}); 
$('#btn-submit-form').on('click', bootboxConfirmation);
```

Comment: I'm personally a fan of the second notation, simply because it keeps the code more modular, and helps manage Callback Hell http://callbackhell.com/ I'm not sure if it has any bearing on the performance of the code itself.

Comment: thanks that link about callbackhell is very informative. I also prefer the second notation.

Comment: See http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/jsFunc/index.html for when it makes sense to use `var functionName = function(){}`

Comment: you don't need to worry anymore about memory leaks and performance is not a factor on seldom-executing code like click handlers.